# Python win32com registered class don't work in excel vba when compiled white pyinstaller

Tags: python, excel, pyinstaller, win32com

I'm trying to compile a test program that register a class object in python for use in excel vba

The code is quite simple, it just register the class using win32, the class just return the string it receive as argument

Then in excel vba I use vba.createobject("pythonObjectName") to use it's methods directly in excel vba

Everything works fine from my python file

When I compile it with pyinstaller to use on PC's that don't have python installed, the python exe works well.

The problem is that when I tried to use vba.createobject("pythonObjectName"), at that point excel vba gives an error saying "failed to run server"

I have other problems on this try, but I found solutions, but this one I don't even have idea of what is causing the problem, thanks in advise.

Comment: If you look at the Registry Entry for "pythonObjectName" what is the executable? Go to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT and search for your name (ProgId). You should find a CLSID key, with a sub-key of "LocalServer32", and the Data in that should be the command line that the system uses to run your server.

Comment: @DS_London, thanks for the help, I opened the registry and found a folder with the ProgId, in this case is "Python.TestNoPassWordCompiledEleven", there is a subfolder named "CLSID", I found a file there, the type is "REG_SZ" and the data is the CLSID, I don't find the sub-key "LocalServer32", thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you have the CLSID, then do a search for that next.

Comment: thanks, i have found this, i did some mo research and found the problem, still don't know why lol.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution
basically, my code was only registering the class, it was not making it available for using in excel vba when compiled, the solution was change de code under if **name**== "**main**"

it was like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(Controller)
```

now it is:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     if '--register' in sys.argv or '--unregister' in sys.argv:
        win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(Controller)
    else:
        win32com.server.localserver.serve([pythonTestLibraryFinal._reg_clsid_ ])
```

then, once compiled, i call the in command line with:

```
testlib.exe --register
```

it register the class
and to make it available to vba:

```
testlib.exe
```

thanks for the help of the comunity, here are the link to the [post](https://dzmns.co/how-to-build-a-com-visible-executable-with-python/) that help me out in this too